# How to pass a string from Mainactivity.class to ContentProvider.class in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

***MainActivity.class***

```
public static String data="Some text here";
```

***ContentProvider.class***

```
private synchronized void readContentFile(@NonNull Context context)

{

  //I Need to get the String data here..

}
```

not able to use getIntent(); inside this class

Comment: String d = MainActivity.data;

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? whats your goal?

Comment: it is returning as null

Comment: @pskink  i will have card view in main activity 
based on the selection of my card some text will be stored to String data
then i will have to call this to content provider class
but content provider class always returns null

Comment: what Uri are you using? What do you need that content provider for?

Comment: @pskink android.net.uri
Actually i am creating a sticker pack for whatsapp
i need to load .json file(in ContentProvider class) based on the selection in main activity

Comment: json file? what json file?? sorry i really have no idea what you are trying to do..  so you have a custom content provider, right? what next?

Comment: so cannot you use `insert` / `update` methods to pass your `String`?

Comment: how it can be done any reference link ?